# SSRS report filepath parameters

Tags: sql-server-2022, ssrs-2019

I'm trying to migrate reports over to a new SSRS 2019 server and one particular report gets called from an excel macro where it reads in the contents of a file located at a given filepath.

I've tried the methods of defining the report path as described on the Microsoft site which is

```
http://server/ReportServer?/foldername/reportname&parametername="filepath"
```

I've tried sever different ways to pass the file url in as a parameter but every time it comes up as an error

> path of the item is not valid.

The file exists on a network server and if I run the report manually from the report sever I can just pass in the network url as follows `"\\<server>\<folder>\<subfolder>\filename.txt"` and it works as expected.

When I try to run this by passing in the filepath into the url and running from a browser it tells my invalid path.

Long story short, how do you pass in a network server filepath that is not local to the report server as a param?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the correct syntax is as follows for a native report:

```
http://<Server>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2f<Folder>%2f<ReportName>&rs:Command=Render&FileName=<NetworkFilePath>
```